# short way to toggle variable between true and false

Tags: jquery

Very often I need to toggle a variable between true/false, i.e. 0/1.

```
var clicked = 0;

$("#story > p").click(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {clicked = 1}
    else {clicked = 0};
});
```

Is it possible something like this:

```
$("#story > p").click(function() {
clicked.toggle (0,1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try

```
clicked = clicked ^ 1;
```

as long as `clicked` has value 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **conditional operator** (? :)

```
var clicked = 0;

$("#story > p").click(function() {
    clicked = clicked ? 0 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also check this *funny* solution:

```
clicked = !clicked*1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var clicked;
 $("#story > p").click(function () {
     clicked = clicked ? 0 : 1;
 });
```